# Why current date is showing next date from the current date in php?

Tags: php

I want to get current date in php but it is displaying one day advance.

I am surprised why this is happening as I am using very simple code:

```
date('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: Please check with the time zone

Comment: like date_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: its timezone issue so set your timezone first.

Comment: @AjeetSingh i have posted an answer please try that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set date time zone as IST. Then try. May your server config time zone is USA. So please add below lines in your code and check it

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d-m-Y');
```

For more about PHP date time please visit [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this function `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok")`